# Null-able integer on c#

Tags: c#, get, null, set, nullable

I have this code

```
public long? UnitId { get; set; }
```

and unitId is Null-able

with that code, when the value was null,on web-api the result for showing is also "null"

how can I change the result to the something like this:

```
if(UnitId ==null) UnitId =0;
```

my mean is, can I set "if(UnitId ==null) UnitId =0;" to the get set ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking about - `if ...` code you've shown works fine...

Comment: well that is the way to do it... `if(UnitId==null) UnitId=0;` or `UnitId=UnitId.HasValue?UnitId.Value:0` but does not setting to `0` defeats the purpose of having it `Nullable` in first place.

Comment: @EliPerl    my mean is, can I set "if(UnitId ==null) UnitId =0;" to the get set ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to detect the null and return 0 in the [get accessor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/aa287786(v=vs.71).aspx).

You can do something like this:

```
private long? unitId;
public long? UnitId
{
    get
    {
        return unitId ?? 0;
    }
    set
    {
        unitId = value;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't really solve any problems.  You can only do this if the variable type is nullable.

The only thing this offers is that you can assert your `nullable long` is never null... which seems odd since you could just define it as `long`, and instead catch where it may possibly be set as null.

Comment: I got an error: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Application.Model.dll" all I want is when the result is null, instead of null , show another integer like zero

Comment: Then do what @EliPerl suggested above: `var v = UnitId ?? 0;`.  This is functionally equivalent to `var v; if(UnitId != null) {v = UnitId} else {v = 0;}`

Comment: I just can use "if" on get/set :(

Comment: These arbitrary requirements sound like homework, and we've given you enough to do that.  Combine my comment above with this answer and you have `if on get/set`.

Comment: public long? UnitId
        {
            get
            {
                return UnitId ?? 0;
            }
            set
            {
                if (UnitId == null)
                    UnitId = value;
            }
        }                  error:An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Application.Model.dll

Comment: Pay attention to capitalisation. There are _two different_ variables here. Also read the link I provided to get/set accessor information article.